# PBSPro qsub Output File Name for Job Array

Tags: pbs

It is desirable to have PBSPro std output files that are easily understood while making use of job arrays. I have not found a way.

Here are a set of jobs for discussion -

```
Job id            Name             User              Time Use S Queue 
----------------  ---------------- ----------------  -------- - -----  
651902.srvname    pl_0000          xxxxxxxxx         00:00:00 R large  
651903[].srvname  dp_0000-0001     xxxxxxxxx                0 H large     
651904.srvname    bp_0100          xxxxxxxxx                0 H large  
651905[].srvname  dp_0000-bpx6     xxxxxxxxx                0 H large
```

Running qsub without changing the output name results in files for each of the subjobs for job arrays. For example, the following files are produced for job 651905[]:

```
651905[1].srvname.OU  
651905[2].srvname.OU  
...  
651905[x].srvname.OU
```

Using qsub -o [JOBNAME] which is known when launching, results in a single file for the job array id so that the std output is only available for one of the subjobs.

The desired output file set is:

```
dp_0000-bpx6[1].OU     
dp_0000-bpx6[2].OU
...
dp_0000-bpx6[x].OU
```

**How can this be accomplished? In other words, how can the output file name be set to something more understandable while preserving the array index?**

A secondary question is how can I include the sequence number along with the job name? Something like -

```
dp_0000-bpx6.651905[1].OU     
dp_0000-bpx6.651905[2].OU
...
dp_0000-bpx6.651905[x].OU
```

Answer (score 0):

This won't get you fully there, but close.

```
qsub -J "0-512:512" -N pl_0000 -o pl_0000.^array_index^ -- /usr/bin/echo "HI"
```

Produces this output.  You can see each array index with their own output.

```
-rw------- 1 pbsdev pbsdev     3 Apr 29 21:00 pl_0000.0
-rw------- 1 pbsdev pbsdev     3 Apr 29 21:00 pl_0000.512
-rw------- 1 pbsdev pbsdev     0 Apr 29 21:00 pl_0000.e1441.0
-rw------- 1 pbsdev pbsdev     0 Apr 29 21:00 pl_0000.e1441.512
```

This one will take the jobid and put it in the output filename along with the index.

```
jobid=$(qsub -h -J "0-512:512" -N pl_0000 -- /usr/bin/echo "HI") && qalter -o pl_0000.${jobid}.^array_index^.OU ${jobid} && qrls ${jobid}; echo ${jobid}

1446[].pdw-s1
```

Produces this output.  You can see each jobid and array index with their own output.

```
drwxrwxr-x 2 root   pbsdev 69632 Apr 29 21:05 .
drwxrwxr-x 6 root   pbsdev 20480 Apr 29 20:49 ..
-rw------- 1 pbsdev pbsdev     3 Apr 29 21:05 pl_0000.1446[].pdw-s1.0.OU
-rw------- 1 pbsdev pbsdev     3 Apr 29 21:05 pl_0000.1446[].pdw-s1.512.OU
-rw------- 1 pbsdev pbsdev     0 Apr 29 21:05 pl_0000.e1446.0
-rw------- 1 pbsdev pbsdev     0 Apr 29 21:05 pl_0000.e1446.512


JOBID     v            v Array Index
pl_0000.1446[].pdw-s1.512.OU
```

You can add a -e and change the error output in the qalter.  Note, the -h is needed to hold the job, so then qalter has time to modify it, then qrls releases it.